# Python file (.py) converted to .exe fails to execute (Python 3.4 + cx_Freeze)

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, cx-freeze

I converted simple "Hello world ... press enter" script, and converted it to .exe using cx_Freeze module. It runs fine. When i tried to convert littlebit complex script and run it, I got problem. The script it self runs perfect but .exe  wouldn't work.

symptom: .exe starts, command line flashes once and nothing happens.

Scripts structure: Uses only os module and sys module.

Scripts funktions: basicly reads and writes a .txt file

script flow:
1. changes cwd
2. opens .txt
3. reads .txt to a list
4. changes the cell in a list where certain string is located
5. writes the list back in the file
6. closes the file 
7. waits to user in put to end (sys.stdin.readline())

I cant figure out what is wrong.

```
import os
import sys

#change cwd
os.chdir('S:/user_name/')       

#locate the line where "sertain_string: False" is
file = open('Test_dir/test.txt', 'r+')   
lines= file.readlines()
file.close()

x = 0
while(lines[x] != "certain_string: False\n"):
    x = x + 1
    continue
else:
    print("certain_string is on line", + x)
print("\n")

#Read the lines to the list
file = open('Test_dir/test.txt', 'r+')    
lines = fiel.readlines()
file.close()
print("\n")

#Change the cell where "certain_string: false" is to "certain_string: True"
lines[x] = 'certain_string: True\n'

print("\n")

#write the list back to the file
file = open('Test_dir/test.txt', 'w+')    
file.writelines(lines)
file.close()
print("Done... press enter:")

r = sys.stdin.readline()
```

I run .exe file from command line.

Error report:

```
cf_freeze console.py line 26: 
Code = importer.get_code(moduleName)
zipimport.ZipImportError: Can't find module 'client_v.0.02__main__'.
```

I don't understand this. It tries to find client_v.0.02__main__ module from the .zip file, which is module library created during .py to .exe convertion.
My .py file name is "Client_v.0.02".

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: Try executing it using command line. This way, after your program quits, you'll still be able to see eventual stack trace/error report or any other standard output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out. My scripts file name was the issue. During conversion, cx_freeze made module library .zip, but the location of the scripts **main** module was affected by the name. A dot in the name made a subdirectory to library .zip file so the path to **main** was wrong and couldn't be found.